# Using Reg Exp to replace string that is unique in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write this script in Perl to check for a unique string inside the variable $summary from my query results. There is multiple similar entries like this but part of them are unique (db1node1web1 could be different nodes but same result type). This is only a small part of the code to check if I using Reg Ex correctly (not true currently).

I included the code below:

```
$summary = "NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_db1node1web1 CRITICAL - load average: 114.49, 48.55, 29.17 Sept 01 00:10:16 PDT 2012";
if ( $summary =~ "NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_[a-z]* CRITICAL - load average: 114.49, 48.55, 29.17 Sept 01 00:10:16 PDT 2012") {
    print "True\n";
}else {
    print "False\n";
}
```

I am very bad with Perl and trying to get this working so I can dissect my query results.

Comment: Try replacing `[a-z]*` with `[a-z0-9]*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a few years since I've coded in perl, but IIRC, don't you have to specify whether it's a match or substitution? And you need to include numbers

I believe your code should be:

```
$summary = "NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_db1node1web1 CRITICAL - load average: 114.49, 48.55, 29.17 Sept 01 00:10:16 PDT 2012";
if ( $summary =~ m/NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_[a-z0-9]* CRITICAL - load average: 114.49, 48.55, 29.17 Sept 01 00:10:16 PDT 2012/) {
    print "True\n";
}else {
    print "False\n";
}
```

Reference: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm

Comment: Thanks for the edit hobbs, you are absolutely correct.  Again, it's been a few years since I've programmed in Perl so forgot about that. ;)

Comment: if ( $summary =~ m/NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_[a-z0-9]*/){

This will return a True result. But I need to go past that and complete the entry. What needs to be done there?

Comment: @user1666605: What do you mean by *complete the entry*?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to match a substring, then specify only that, e.g.

```
$summary =~ /NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_/
```

Comment: That does work. But I am needing to match multiple unique strings which is why I was trying to pick out the unique one with the reg ex

Comment: Which part is the "unique" part that you need to match?  The "db1node1web1"?  Or the load average stats?  Do you mean that you want to _capture_ the "db1node1web1"?  (In that case, ``$summary =~ /NFW - CRITICAL CPU_LOAD_(\w+)/`` would put the string in ``$1``.

Comment: I need to match db1node1web1 with multiple similar nodes that have this same alarm. The load average stats will also be unique to each node(db1node1web1). I am essentially trying to match same alarms from different times + nodes together and count them.

Answer (score 0):

`[a-z]` does not include numbers. Your example string contains several `1`'s. Adjust the class to

```
[a-z0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use slashes for quoting regular expressions instead of double quotes. Also, your input `db1node1web1` contains digits as well as characters:

```
if ( $summary =~ /NFW - CRITICAL CPU_Load_[a-z0-9]* CRITICAL - load average: 114.49, 48.55, 29.17 Sept 01 00:10:16 PDT 2012/) {

  print "True\n";

}else {

  print "False\n";

}
```

Comment: I don't know in detail but AFAIK, at least you should have it like `m"..."`.